# Can Ubuntu Samba Recycle Bin to operate independently of the client windows machine (no settings in them)?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, samba, recycle-bin

Can Ubuntu Samba Recycle Bin to operate independently of the client windows machine (no settings in them)?
Can deleted files restored directly from the Ubuntu Server?